# Can a firm with encryption keys decrypt iCloud keychain data of Chinese users?

Tags: icloud, security, keychain, encryption

Apple has already given all data of Chinese iCloud users to Guizhou on the Cloud Big Data Industrial Development Co., Ltd., (GCBD),  as well as their encryption keys, which means it can decrypt these users' data. However, some iCloud services such as keychain use end to end encryption, which according to Apple: even Apple itself cannot decrypt this data on server. But Apple does not mention whether GCBD can decrypt keychain data of Chinese users or this end to end encryption mechanism is as secure as that for non Chinese users.

So, can GCBD or any third party decrypt iCloud keychain data of Chinese users?